# Message template option missing in send SMS activity in CiviCRM 4.5.8

Tags: sms, message-templates, 4.5

After upgrading a site to CiviCRM 4.5.8 the drop down template selector is missing in the Send SMS activity.

[image: Send SMS Activity Screenshot]

Has anyone else had this problem?

I've upgraded the CiviSMS Extension from 1.0 to 2.0, but this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

The character limit for the message has also jumped from 160 characters to 460 characters, I know I can amend the SMS API settings to allow extended messages. How can I return the character limit in the activity to 160?

Cheers

Craig

Comment: I also have this problem - Civi 4.6.12, Wordpress 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a fix for this - https://github.com/PalanteJon/civicrm-core/commit/a7ea8fd5e8f74ea415d9ac026da4607e5a4da0fd

I'll submit it upstream as soon as I have a minute to write a webtest for it.